# Influxdb problem : "no matching manifest for linux/arm/v7 in the manifest list entries"

Tags: docker, influxdb

I'm currently working on setting up Docker on a Raspberry Pi 3+ to use Grafana,
following a tutorial that advises installing InfluxDB as a prerequisite using the command

```
docker pull influxdb.
```

However, when I run this command, I encounter the following error: "no matching manifest for linux/arm/v7 in the manifest list entries."

Could someone please help me resolve this issue? I'd greatly appreciate any guidance on how to fix it.

Thank you!

I tried with old version, but not solved my problem.

Comment: The error message you're seeing, "no matching manifest for linux/arm/v7 in the manifest list entries," indicates that there is no Docker image available for InfluxDB that is compatible with the architecture of your Raspberry Pi 3+ (which uses an ARMv7 processor).

Comment: Yes, but i'm not sure how to fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue and run InfluxDB on your Raspberry Pi 3+, you can build the InfluxDB Docker image for the ARM architecture manually.

Install Docker on Your Raspberry Pi:
If you haven't already, install Docker on your Raspberry Pi by running these commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install docker.io
```

Pull the InfluxDB Image for ARM:

Instead of pulling the InfluxDB image directly, you can try pulling an ARM-compatible InfluxDB image from a community repository. You can use the arm32v7/influxdb image like this:

```
docker pull arm32v7/influxdb
```

Run InfluxDB Container:

Start an InfluxDB container using the pulled image:

```
docker run -d --name influxdb -p 8086:8086 arm32v7/influxdb
```

This command runs InfluxDB as a container, mapping port 8086 on your Raspberry Pi to the InfluxDB port.

Check InfluxDB Container Status:

You can check if the container is running with:

```
docker ps
```

You should see the influxdb container listed.

Now, InfluxDB should be running on your Raspberry Pi 3+ using Docker. You can proceed with your Grafana setup and configure it to connect to the InfluxDB container for data storage and visualization.

This simplified method should work well for most users, and you don't need to manually build InfluxDB from source. However, it's essential to note that the arm32v7/influxdb image may not always be up-to-date compared to official InfluxDB releases, so make sure it meets your requirements.